Fetching data from DB and binding it to array
In my Angular application currently I have hardcoded the values in an array and binding them to the dropdown list which is working fine, for the dropdown list I am using the control from in-built.
It looks like below currently.
export class UserDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private _userManagemement: UserManagementService){
}

userDetails : IUserDetails = {
 selectedValue: 'tim435'
 items: [
  {
    text: 'tim hoppins',
    value: 'tim435',
    id: 12
  },
  {
    text: 'andrew ramos',
    value: 'and71',
    id: 18
  },
  {
    text: 'jay ronne',
    value: 'jr214',
    id: 21
  }
 ]
 };

}

Now I need to fetch the details dynamically from the database instead of hardcoding it in the code, for that I created an API and I have method in service which calls the endpoint as below.
export class UserManagementService {

  public getUserDetails() {
     return this.httpClient.get('endpoint');
  }

}

What I am not sure is how do I bind the data returned by the method getUserDetails() in service to the items array of userDetails

You can map the response to the structure you need.
public getUserDetails(): Observable<IUserDetails> {
    return this.httpClient.get('endpoint').pipe(map(response => ({
   items: response, selectedValue: response ? response[0]?.value : undefined
 })
}

Then in your component, store the resulting Observable of UserDetails as a component level variable.
userDetails$: Observable<IUserDetails> = service.getUserDetails();

Then in your template, bind where you need these using userDetails$ | async to subscribe/unsubscribe automatically.
<select>
    <option *ngFor="let userDetail of (userDetails$ | async)?.items" value="userDetail.value">
       {{ userDetail.text }}
    </option>
</select>


I see compile issues in getUserDetails() method from (map(response onwards also the number opening ( and closing ) do not match..

This is more about the approach than copy/paste code. Map the response to the structure you need, subscribe/unsubscribe in your template with AsyncPipe.
